# Continued numbered list in openxml

Tags: php, list, ms-word, openxml

I have continued numbered list.

That's my XML code :

```
<w:p>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
      <w:numPr>
         <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
         <w:numId w:val="1"/>
      </w:numPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr></w:rPr>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve">toto</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
      <w:numPr>
         <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
         <w:numId w:val="1"/>
      </w:numPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr></w:rPr>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve">toto</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

and that's my output :

1. toto
2. toto
3. cornichon
4. cornichon

**I want this :**

1. toto
2. toto

   1. cornichon
   2. cornichon

**Advance Thanks,**

Comment: What has this to do with PHP? Where do the cornichons come from?

Comment: Because I generated my Word in php with this XML code. The 'cornichon' is like 'toto' string => is the same code of 'toto'

Answer (score 0):

DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, ODT, ect files are actually zipped XML files.

So you can create the desired format in the word editor, then unzip the file. If you had a docx file, then you will see 3 folders in the unzipped version. The word\document will contains the right XML for you. There you can examine how the desired structure would look like if you would generate the same structure with PHP.

My test file ODT(LibreOffice Word format):
[image]

`content.xml`, which describes the questioned structure part(ODT file):

```
 <text:list xml:id="list1418357962" text:style-name="L1">
    <text:list-item>
       <text:p text:style-name="P2">asd</text:p>
    </text:list-item>
    <text:list-item>
       <text:p text:style-name="P2">asd</text:p>
       <text:list>
          <text:list-item>
             <text:p text:style-name="P2">asd</text:p>
          </text:list-item>
          <text:list-item>
             <text:p text:style-name="P2">asd</text:p>
          </text:list-item>
       </text:list>
    </text:list-item>
 </text:list>
 <text:p text:style-name="P1" />
```

I also saved the document as `.docx` file. There the `word\document.xml` looks like this:

```
<w:body>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>Asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:numPr>
               <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:numPr>
               <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:numPr>
               <w:ilvl w:val="1" />
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:numPr>
               <w:ilvl w:val="1" />
               <w:numId w:val="1" />
            </w:numPr>
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
            <w:t>asd</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
            <w:bidi w:val="0" />
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
            <w:rPr />
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr />
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:sectPr>
         <w:type w:val="nextPage" />
         <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" />
         <w:pgMar w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:header="0" w:top="1134" w:footer="0" w:bottom="1134" w:gutter="0" />
         <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal" />
         <w:formProt w:val="false" />
         <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb" />
         <w:docGrid w:type="default" w:linePitch="600" w:charSpace="32768" />
      </w:sectPr>
   </w:body>
```

It's likely that it has a lot of extra tags, because it's a converted format, and the converter doesn't do a very good job. But you can use Word, a zip app and a simple text editor to figure out an optimized format. When you modify the XML you can put it back, zip it back and check the result with Word.